# How to find the residue of $f$ at $z_0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

I know how to find residue:

1. finding the pole and order of it.
2. then using the residue formula we get:

$$\operatorname{Res}_{z_0} f = \tfrac{1}{\left(n-1\right)!}\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{n-1}}{\mathrm{d} z^{n-1}}[(z-a)^nf(z)]$$

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{\exp\left(\frac{z^2-\pi/3}{\sqrt 2}\right)}+1$$ at point $z_0= \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\cdot (\sqrt 3-i)$.

So I know how to do this if there was no exp in the denominator the exp makes me confused. The steps stated above are what I did for my other examples and I got the right answer however in this this exp makes me so confused. Any help, please.

Comment: I will edit the question but you should definitely learn how to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @vitamind thanks a lot. I searched a lot to find the MathJax I didn't know the name. so thanks for that I'll keep it in mind and learn.

Comment: Isn't it zero?   $e^z $ doesn't have any zeros.

Comment: @SomeoneiiKnows The function $f(z)$ is bounded for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @vitamind then it would be constant.   Which it clearly isn't.

Comment: @ChrisCuster How does boundess imply a constant function? For what value of $z$ does $f(z)\to\tilde\infty$? Also if there was a value $z$, it's certainly not $\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\cdot (\sqrt 3-i),$ since it clearly [yields](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Cexp%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B%28%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%5Ccdot+%28%5Csqrt+3-i%29%29%5E2-%5Cpi%2F3%7D%7B%5Csqrt+2%7D%5Cright%29%7D%2B1) a finite value.

Comment: I'm thinking of Liouville's theorem.   Isn't  $f $ entire? @vitamind

Comment: @ChrisCuster I think we misunderstand each other. At the end we're trying to say the same thing. You wrote that $e^z$ doesn't have any zeros, looking at $f$ means that we don't have a singularity at $\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\cdot (\sqrt 3-i)$. This should answer the OPs question.

Comment: Ok @vitamind we agree on one thing.  But I don't think it's bounded.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Sorry my mistake. If we let $T\to\infty$ and $z=iT$, then $f$ is not bounded. Well, not an excuse but it's a late here. Thanks for proving me wrong.

Comment: Right.  @vitamind

Answer (score 1):

Your function is *entire*.  That's it has no poles.   Thus the residue is $0$.

Comment: how did you get to know its entire?

Comment: We have the reciprocal of an entire function which is never zero,  plus a constant.   That'll always be entire.  For instance the derivative exists everywhere.